# Problems with font on scss

Tags: angular, ionicons, ng-packagr

I'm using ng-packager to create my own package of alert with angular, that uses the ionicons package.

The package link is https://www.npmjs.com/package/jtp-alert and the project is open, and is in https://github.com/jtpdev/ng-alert.

But when I installs the jtp-alert:

> npm install --save jtpdev

and I'll go to use that, the fonts of scss files are not found.

[image: ionicons_not_found]

and the console shows:

[image: ionicons_font_console]

I cannot undertand why the font is searched on the main path.

What can I do, to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the fonts not found, so it's not rendered when npm run packagr. If you are using scss you must set font path pointing to font folder.

To fix this, update alert.component.scss like this

```
$ionicons-font-path: "../../../node_modules/ionicons/fonts";
@import "../../../node_modules/ionicons/scss/ionicons.scss";
```